# ImageLab Program Problem

Tags: geotools

I am new to GeoTools. I was trying the samples in http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/raster/image.html.
I am not able to run the ImageLab sample code. I know it would be some lack in understanding or a simple mistake.

I am getting the following exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Trying to get a reader from an unknown format.
    at org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.UnknownFormat.getReader(UnknownFormat.java:62)
    at org.geotools.demo.ImageLab.displayLayers(ImageLab.java:93)
    at org.geotools.demo.ImageLab.getLayersAndDisplay(ImageLab.java:77)
    at org.geotools.demo.ImageLab.main(ImageLab.java:51)

What actually needs to be done?  Also, is it possible to use normal jpeg image or any other way around?

In the GeoTools website the mentioned bluemarble.tif is not available and I have been using normal jpg image.

In another website while seraching for more info on this, I read that it uses a world file. What is a world file and how it is related to this and how do I use it?

Please help, I have been stuck with this for a long time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that i am not using maven, rather i am using java eclipse ganeymede.

Comment: just to say that trying to do GeoTools development without maven is very hard and will probably fail.

Answer (score 1):

This error will occur if the image file path or name is wrong. Another possibility is that GeoTools is not properly installed.

Comment: thanks for the reply. it got solved. had missed few geotools jars like imageio-ext-*

Comment: How did you import the jars in eclipse ?